# Why does the compiler version appear in my ELF executable?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, elf

I've recently compiled a simple hello world C program under Debian Linux using gcc:

```
gcc -mtune=native -march=native -m32 -s -Wunused -O2 -o hello hello.c
```

The file size was 2980 bytes. I opened it in a hex editor and i saw the following lines:

```
GCC: (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5 GCC: (Debian 4.4.5-10) 4.4.5 .shstrtab .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rel.dyn .rel.plt .init .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame .ctors .dtors .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt data.data .bss .comment
```

Are they really needed? No way to reduce executable size?

Comment: Not really a answer for the title question but for the second one: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Comment: Is 2980 bytes a problem? Would 2900 be any better?

Comment: @RedX thanks for the link but i've already seen many articles like that one. that's assembler but i am speaking about pure C code.

Comment: This is typical overhead for C code. For a "Hello World", it seems like a lot, yes, but for any more complex binary, it quickly shrinks to noise. You can try playing with running `strip` on it with various flags (GCC's `-s` isn't necessarily optimal for all cases), but unless you want to drop to assembly and stop linking with dynamic libraries, you're not going to really get anywhere.

Comment: +1 from a size standpoint this is minor, but from an **information leak** standpoint this is major, and thus a very worthwhile question. I can think of many situations where you might not want information that could nearly-uniquely identify the machine a binary was generated on embedded in that binary.

Comment: @R..: Huh? First of all, thousands of machines around the world are likely to have that exact build of GCC on them. Second, why is someone distributing binaries while trying to hide? I certainly wouldn't run pre-compiled apps from someone actively seeking to remain anonymous. If they want me to run something, they're going to have to give me the source and I'll build it myself. I don't really see any practical scenario in which this is an issue.

Comment: If your compiler is self-compiled itself, rather than from a major distribution, then that leaks a lot more information. A better example than compilers is video encoders. The version information ffmpeg and mencoder embed in the output file can be personally identifying if you built the tool from source yourself. With code I'll admit most of the time you have something to hide with *code* it's a bad sign, but in some cases there may be very legitimate reasons that I probably shouldn't bring up lest off-topic arguments over freedom and code ethics break out...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's in a comment section in the ELF binary. You can strip it out:

```
$ gcc -m32 -O2 -s -o t t.c
$ ls -l t
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me users 5488 Jun  7 11:58 t
$ readelf -p .comment t

String dump of section '.comment':
  [     0]  GCC: (Gentoo 4.5.1-r1 p1.4, pie-0.4.5) 4.5.1
  [    2d]  GCC: (Gentoo 4.5.2 p1.1, pie-0.4.5) 4.5.2


$ strip -R .comment t


$ readelf -p .comment t
readelf: Warning: Section '.comment' was not dumped because it does not exist!
$ ls -l t
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me users 5352 Jun  7 11:58 t
```

The gains are tiny though, not sure it's worth it.

Comment: ae! got **-24** bytes, thanks. BUT, is there a way to do it in one line? something like postprocessor instructions?

Comment: I'm not aware of one, can't find anything in the `gcc` or `ld` man pages.

Comment: Why are there two entries with two different compiler versions?

Answer (score 15):

use -Qn to avoid that.

```
aa$ touch hello.c
aa$ gcc -c hello.c 
aa$ objdump -s hello.o 

hello.o:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 00474343 3a202844 65626961 6e20342e  .GCC: (Debian 4.
 0010 372e322d 35292034 2e372e32 00        7.2-5) 4.7.2.   
aa$ gcc -Qn -c hello.c 
aa$ objdump -s hello.o 

hello.o:     file format elf32-i386

aa$ gcc -v 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: i486-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i486-linux-gnu --host=i486-linux-gnu --target=i486-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) 
aa$
```

Comment: @bzeaman, [GCC Online Docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/System-V-Options.html) states: `-Qn Refrain from adding .ident directives to the output file.`

Answer (score 4):

This is in a comment section which isn't loaded in memory (and note that ELF files usually use padding so that memory mapping them will keep a correct alignment).  If you want to get rid of such unneeded sections, see the various objcopy options and find out:

```
objcopy --remove-section .comment a.o b.o
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue myself, but using MinGW's GCC implementation - stripping the executable and passing the -Qn option did nothing, and I couldn't remove the ".comment" section as there wasn't one.

In order to stop the compiler including this information, regardless of which sections are in your executable, you can pass the **-fno-ident** parameter to the compiler and linker:

Without the parameter (strings -a [filename]):

```
!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
.text
0`.rdata
0@.idata
GCC: (tdm64-2) 4.8.1
```

With the parameter:

```
!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
.text
0`.idata
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you'd be able to 'just' strip that if you don't want it; See this page for a nice run-down.

http://timelessname.com/elfbin/

Note that the page (of course) also resorts to using assembly, which you may not want to do, but the general gist applies

Comment: @develroot: Not necessarily, see my comment above. `-s` and `strip` are not necessarily equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can inform the loader which sections to include in your output with a linker script.  You can see what sections are included in the file using the objdump command.  As you've noticed there's a good bit of 'junk' in an elf - junk that is until you wish you had it.

Note though, that the size of an elf executable file is not indicative of the memory foot print of the image as realized in memory.  A lot of the 'junk' isn't in the memory image and the image can call sbreak and or mmap to acquire more memory, the elf file takes no account of stack usage - essentially all of your automatic variables are unaccounted for.  These are only three examples others abound.